# Conditional display of fields in CP entry screen, based on other fields' value/state

Tags: add-on, conditionals, entry

Is it possible to show / hide certain form fields on an entry page depending on whether or not, say a checkbox is selected? Hoping for an add-in that can handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're only concerned with showing/hiding fields based on user choice, the [**Entry Type**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-type) add-on would do the trick. It is "a dropdown fieldtype that shows/hides other fields on the publish page" based on the chosen option.

Answer (score 1):

This has been covered [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/6293/293) and [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/5807/293).

I'm not sure that it's similar enough to those to be a duplicate, as they specifically sought to change other fields values, or show/hide fields based on entry ID, but the same technique is used.

You can story jQuery/JavaScript in the Instructions field for one of your fields. That will render HTML, including the contents of a `<script/>` tag.

In that `<script/>` tag, you can use jQuery to show/hide the other field based on the value of the checkbox field and an onchange event.